# How is randomness of the branch migration process ensured?

Tags: molecular-genetics, recombination

Branch migration (part of genetic recombination) is a random process. It looks like Ruv-ABC proteins are mainly responsible for this process, but how is randomness ensured? After all, it can only be a quasi-random process - i.e. molecules don't behave randomly. Is it thermal motion perhaps?